# Http connection pool timeout error has shown me when I run my telegram bot (aiogram)

Tags: python, python-requests, cpanel

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from aiogram import types
from data.config import ADMINS
from loader import dp, db, bot

link = 'http://example.com/'

@dp.message_handler(text="✅ Confirm (1-step)", user_id=ADMINS, state="*")
async def scrapping1(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Confirmed ✅")
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'
        res = s.get(link, timeout=3)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')   
        payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}         
        payload['LoginForm[username]'] = "blabla"
        payload['LoginForm[password]'] = "blabla"

        print(payload)
        s.post(link,data=payload, timeout=3)
        for id in range(10, 100):
            try:
                r = s.get(f'http://example.com?id={id}', timeout=1)
                response = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
```

And it shows an error in cPanel, same thing in Heroku but it works, is there any package or code should I use?

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /bla/bla (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2b2341447280>, 'Connection to example.com timed out. (connect timeout=3)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

your remote url `example.com/bla/bla/` is unreachable while bot itself is working
remove `try` (which has no `except`) and then you will fail fast to find out more

Comment: I actually didn't want to put which website I want to parse, so `example.com/bla/bla` is just an example, and `try` has `catch` but I didn't show it, I mean code is correct but server responds different, I put my bot on `cPanel` but couldn't parse, but when I put it on `Heroku` server and it worked